# Json serialization near to what is shown in prettyPrint() method output

Tags: java, diff, javers

I'm trying to export the diff data to my front-end using the json converter of javers but I cant get the same thing shown in Diff.prettyPrint() return which contains the "'field' from 'x' to 'y'"... the json output include some useless data and even the order of the data shown is different from one to another.

My actual code:

```
Diff diff = javers.compare(projOriginal,projNew);
String diffJson = javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(diff);
```

The output of the same diff variable:
PrettyPrint:

```
* object removed: myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito/5
* new object: myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito/7
* changes on myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito/7 :
  - 'descricao' changed from '' to 'requisito 1'
  - 'id' changed from '' to '7'
* changes on myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Risco/6 :
  - 'fatorPriorizacao' changed from '0.10' to '0.100000000000000006'
* new object: myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito/8
* changes on myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito/8 :
  - 'descricao' changed from '' to 'lionel messi'
  - 'id' changed from '' to '8'
* changes on myproj.domain.entity.usuario.Usuario/1 :
  - 'ultimoAcesso' changed from '29 ago 2018, 14:50:28' to '05 set 2018, 14:35:29'
* changes on myproj.domain.entity.projeto.dto.ProjetoDTO/2 :
  - 'avisoComplexidade' changed from 'true' to 'false'
  - 'requisitosList' collection changes :
    0. '...Requisito/5' changed to '...Requisito/8'
    1. '...Requisito/7' added
```

JsonConverter:

```
{
  "changes": [
    {
      "changeType": "NewObject",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
        "cdoId": 8
      }
    },
    {
      "changeType": "NewObject",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
        "cdoId": 7
      }
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ObjectRemoved",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
        "cdoId": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
        "cdoId": 7
      },
      "property": "descricao",
      "left": null,
      "right": "requisito 1"
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
        "cdoId": 7
      },
      "property": "id",
      "left": null,
      "right": 7
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
        "cdoId": 8
      },
      "property": "descricao",
      "left": null,
      "right": "lionel messi"
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
        "cdoId": 8
      },
      "property": "id",
      "left": null,
      "right": 8
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.dto.ProjetoDTO",
        "cdoId": 2
      },
      "property": "avisoComplexidade",
      "left": true,
      "right": false
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ListChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.dto.ProjetoDTO",
        "cdoId": 2
      },
      "property": "requisitosList",
      "elementChanges": [
        {
          "elementChangeType": "ElementValueChange",
          "index": 0,
          "leftValue": {
            "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
            "cdoId": 5
          },
          "rightValue": {
            "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
            "cdoId": 8
          }
        },
        {
          "elementChangeType": "ValueAdded",
          "index": 1,
          "value": {
            "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Requisito",
            "cdoId": 7
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.projeto.Risco",
        "cdoId": 6
      },
      "property": "fatorPriorizacao",
      "left": 0.10,
      "right": 0.100000000000000006
    },
    {
      "changeType": "ValueChange",
      "globalId": {
        "entity": "myproj.domain.entity.usuario.Usuario",
        "cdoId": 1
      },
      "property": "ultimoAcesso",
      "left": "2018-08-29T14:50:28.837",
      "right": "2018-09-05T14:35:29.928"
    }
  ]
}
```

Another HUGE problem is that I can't see the path where the objects were attached on... Lets say I do have an User attached to my graph in "projetoDTO.masterUser", and other in "projetoDTO.requisito.userThatManagesIt": If a change occurs I will never know from where the user is/was just that an User was modified.
Any toughts?
Ty

**Edit**

Another thing is that I know that an object was removed...and that is it! Using a Long as @Id I can't know what was removed, since the "1" is not relevant to the user. Any ideas too? Maybe an withDeletedObjects(true) like is for new objects is available?

Comment: Can you post the output from these two commands?

Comment: @mattdonders posted :D

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question, diff as json and diff pretty print conveys the same information but in different form